# Complex android layout (overlapping, left/right align, center align)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create the following layout on an Android device:

[image: Layout]

The requirements are as follows:
First layout which occupies the whole screen (fill_parent);
Second (at the bottom of the screen) overlays the first one and has the following formats:

- 3 columns;
- occupies the whole screen width;
- arrows are aligned left and right sides, and text area is resized based on screen width;

I've tried numerous things, but since I'm new to the Android world, I had no success yet.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/RootView">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/mapImageView" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomArea"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/adsArea"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/leftArrow"
                android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is some summary text" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/rightArrow"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnNext" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but the text doesn't seem to be center aligned, nor resized to the screen width:

[image]

Does someone has a clue?

Thanks.

Comment: Post whatever you've tried and what exactly doesn't seem to be working in that. Though I must admit, I liked the graphics you've posted!!

Comment: What have you tried? And show us problem snap/code if you are facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below. Also, do not use multiple viewgroup for simple layout solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RootView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/adsArea"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/leftArrow" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is some summary text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/rightArrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code for your required layout**...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightButton1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftButton1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is some summary text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```